# SQL Query to get data from 4 tables - to CAST and SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, dynamic-sql

I  got stuck with a old query

This query returns Closing Stock value of all items in my Inventory

Original Scenario TABLES:

**T1: DETAIL_PURCHASE**

**T2: PURCHASE_REPORT**

**T3: DETAIL_SALE**

**T4: SALE_REPORT**

**DETAIL_PURCHASE** HAS COLUMNS *ITEMID,QTYSOLD,BILLNO*

**PURCHASE_REPORT** HAS COLUMNS *BILLNO,BILLDATE*

**DETAIL_SALE** HAS COLUMNS ITEMID,QTYSOLD,BILLNO

**SALE_REPORT** HAS COLUMNS BILLNO,BILLDATE

The Query I am looking for is to sum all QTY in DETAIL_PURCHASE of each Individual Items DIFFERENCE with sum all QTY in DETAIL_SALE of each Individual Items With a Date filter query using dates in SALE_REPORT & PURCHASE_REPORT.

```
SELECT
  dp.ITEMNAME,
  SUM(CAST(dp.QUANTITY AS numeric(18, 2))) - SUM(CAST(ds.QTY AS numeric(18, 2))) AS [ClosingStock]
FROM detailpurchases AS dp
JOIN purchasereport AS pr
  ON dp.BARCODE = pr.voucherno
JOIN detailsale AS ds
  ON ds.ITEMN = dp.ITEMN
JOIN salesreport AS sr
  ON ds.BARCODE = sr.voucherno
WHERE ds.T = 'R'
AND pr.voucherdate BETWEEN '" & DATE1.Text & "' AND '" & DATE2.Text & "'
AND sr.voucherdate BETWEEN '" & DATE1.Text & "' AND '" & DATE2.Text & "'
GROUP BY dp.ITEMNAME;
```

The above query I worked out but it still returns wrong value. More likely Far greater value than needed.

Example Table:

DETAILPURCHASE:

```
ID  SN  ITEMN   BARCODE ITEMNAME    HSN T   CP  BID BATCHN  QUANTITY
282 1   106 0009    5STAR 10.1G 5/- 18063100    0   230.11011           90.0
330 2   106 0014    5STAR 10.1G 5/- 18063100    0   3.979876543         4860.0
332 2   106 0015    5STAR 10.1G 5/- 18063100    0   3.8397736           4860.0
385 3   106 0021    5STAR 10.1G 5/- 18063100    0   210.73944           144.0
446 1   106 0025    5STAR 10.1G 5/- 18063100    0   230.1099            108.0
545 6   106 0034    5STAR 10.1G 5/- 18063100    0   225.34766   1       90.0
598 1   106 0039    5STAR 10.1G 5/- 18063100    0   230.109944          180.0
671 1   106 0044    5STAR 10.1G 5/- 18063100    1   222.80137   54  832 270.0
814 1   106 0070    5STAR 10.1G 5/- 18063100    1   222.80  369 906 108.0
```

DETAILSALE:

```
ID  SN  ITEMN   BARCODE ITEMNAME    HSN T   CP  BIID    BATCHN  QTY
59  12  106 0214    5STAR 10.1G 5/- 18063100    R   222.8   54  832 2.0
94  7   106 0218    5STAR 10.1G 5/- 18063100    R   222.8   54  832 18.0
111 8   106 0220    5STAR 10.1G 5/- 18063100    R   222.8   54  832 5.0
163 1   106 0225    5STAR 10.1G 5/- 18063100    R   222.8   54  832 1.0
189 17  106 0227    5STAR 10.1G 5/- 18063100    R   222.8   54  832 1.0
257 13  106 0231    5STAR 10.1G 5/- 18063100    R   222.8   54  832 5.0
303 12  106 0232    5STAR 10.1G 5/- 18063100    R   222.8   54  832 4.0
359 22  106 0235    5STAR 10.1G 5/- 18063100    R   222.8   54  832 5.0
379 14  106 0236    5STAR 10.1G 5/- 18063100    R   222.8   54  832 2.0
497 1   106 0293    5STAR 10.1G 5/- 18063100    R   222.8   369 906 2.0
516 1   106 0291    5STAR 10.1G 5/- 18063100    R   222.8   369 906 18.0
```

PURCHASEREPORT:

```
ID  VOUCHERTYPE VOUCHERDATE        VOUCHERNO     PARTY
15  Purchase    2017-07-21 00:00:00.000 0006    VINAYAKA CORPORATION
16  Purchase    2017-07-14 00:00:00.000 0002    SAI MAHESWARA AGENCIES
17  Purchase    2017-07-11 00:00:00.000 0001    SATHYA TRADING CO
18  Purchase    2017-07-15 00:00:00.000 0003    CHELLU ENTERPRISES
19  Purchase    2017-07-15 00:00:00.000 0004    RITHESH TRADERS
20  Purchase    2017-07-16 00:00:00.000 0005    CHELLU ENTERPRISES
21  Purchase    2017-07-21 00:00:00.000 0006    SRI PRAMEELA MARKETINGS
22  Purchase    2017-07-22 00:00:00.000 0007    RITHESH TRADERS
24  Purchase    2017-07-24 00:00:00.000 0008    SATHYA TRADING CO
25  Purchase    2017-07-29 00:00:00.000 0009    CHELLU ENTERPRISES
26  Purchase    2017-07-31 00:00:00.000 0010    CHELLU ENTERPRISES
27  Purchase    2017-07-31 00:00:00.000 0011    RITHESH TRADERS
30  Purchase    2017-07-31 00:00:00.000 0012    SAI MAHESWARA AGENCIES
31  Purchase    2017-08-09 00:00:00.000 0013    CHELLU ENTERPRISES
32  Purchase    2017-08-09 00:00:00.000 0014    CHELLU ENTERPRISES
33  Purchase    2017-08-09 00:00:00.000 0015    CHELLU ENTERPRISES
34  Purchase    2017-08-09 00:00:00.000 0016    CHELLU ENTERPRISES
35  Purchase    2017-08-08 00:00:00.000 0017    SATHYA TRADING CO
36  Purchase    2017-08-12 00:00:00.000 0018    SRI PRAMEELA MARKETINGS
37  Purchase    2017-08-14 00:00:00.000 0019    RITHESH TRADERS
38  Purchase    2017-08-15 00:00:00.000 0020    CHELLU ENTERPRISES
39  Purchase    2017-08-17 00:00:00.000 0021    CHELLU ENTERPRISES
40  Purchase    2017-08-17 00:00:00.000 0022    SATHYA TRADING CO
41  Purchase    2017-08-21 00:00:00.000 0023    CHELLU ENTERPRISES
42  Purchase    2017-08-28 00:00:00.000 0024    SATHYA TRADING CO
43  Purchase    2017-08-29 00:00:00.000 0025    CHELLU ENTERPRISES
45  Purchase    2017-08-31 00:00:00.000 0027    SAI MAHESWARA AGENCIES
46  Purchase    2017-08-31 00:00:00.000 0028    SRI VINAYAKA AGENCIES 
47  Purchase    2017-08-31 00:00:00.000 0026    RITHESH TRADERS
48  Purchase    2017-09-11 00:00:00.000 0027    SATHYA TRADING CO
49  Purchase    2017-09-14 00:00:00.000 0028    RITHESH TRADERS
50  Purchase    2017-09-15 00:00:00.000 0029    RITHESH TRADERS
51  Purchase    2017-09-06 00:00:00.000 0030    SRI PRAMEELA MARKETINGS
52  Purchase    2017-09-08 00:00:00.000 0031    MOKSHITHA ENTERPRISES
53  Purchase    2017-09-09 00:00:00.000 0032    SAI MAHESWARA AGENCIES
54  Purchase    2017-09-09 00:00:00.000 0033    SRI VINAYAKA AGENCIES 
55  Purchase    2017-09-15 00:00:00.000 0034    CHELLU ENTERPRISES
56  Purchase    2017-09-15 00:00:00.000 0035    CHELLU ENTERPRISES
58  Purchase    2017-09-29 00:00:00.000 0036    SATHYA TRADING CO
59  Purchase    2017-09-22 00:00:00.000 0037    CHELLU ENTERPRISES
60  Purchase    2017-09-22 00:00:00.000 0038    RITHESH TRADERS
61  Purchase    2017-09-28 00:00:00.000 0039    CHELLU ENTERPRISES
62  Purchase    2017-09-28 00:00:00.000 0040    RITHESH TRADERS
63  Purchase    2017-09-28 00:00:00.000 0041    RITHESH TRADERS
64  Purchase    2017-09-29 00:00:00.000 0042    SATHYA TRADING CO
65  Purchase    2017-10-09 00:00:00.000 0043    SRI VINAYAKA AGENCIES 
66  Purchase    2017-10-10 00:00:00.000 0044    CHELLU ENTERPRISES
67  Purchase    2017-10-11 00:00:00.000 0045    MOKSHITHA ENTERPRISES
68  Purchase    2017-10-14 00:00:00.000 0046    SATHYA TRADING CO
69  Purchase    2017-10-14 00:00:00.000 0047    RITHESH TRADERS
72  Purchase    2017-10-23 00:00:00.000 0048    CHELLU ENTERPRISES
73  Purchase    2017-10-23 00:00:00.000 0049    CHELLU ENTERPRISES
74  Purchase    2017-10-23 00:00:00.000 0050    CHELLU ENTERPRISES
```

SALEREPORT

```
ID  VOUCHERTYPE VOUCHERDATE     VOUCHERNO   PARTY
4   Sale    2017-10-02 00:00:00.000 0212    SAI MEDICALS
6   HOLD    2017-10-03 00:00:00.000 0214    VAMSI KRISHNA SUPER BAZAAR
7   Sale    2017-10-03 00:00:00.000 0215    ADS SUPER BAZAAR
9   Sale    2017-10-04 00:00:00.000 0217    SRI BALAJI GENARAL STORES
10  Sale    2017-10-04 00:00:00.000 0218    NEW SS BEKERY
11  Sale    2017-10-04 00:00:00.000 0219    KANYAKA PARAMESWARI STORES
12  Sale    2017-10-05 00:00:00.000 0220    VASAVI STORES
13  Sale    2017-10-05 00:00:00.000 0221    NAVEEN
14  Sale    2017-10-05 00:00:00.000 0222    SRI HARI MEDICALS
15  Sale    2017-10-05 00:00:00.000 0223    JAKKAM SHOPPING CORNER
16  Sale    2017-10-05 00:00:00.000 0224    C NARESH
19  Sale    2017-10-05 00:00:00.000 0225    K R C SONS STORES
20  Sale    2017-10-05 00:00:00.000 0226    SREEDHAR TRADERS
21  Sale    2017-10-06 00:00:00.000 0227    B V SHANMUGAM
22  Sale    2017-10-06 00:00:00.000 0228    NEW VENKATESWARA SWEETS
23  Sale    2017-10-07 00:00:00.000 0229    VIJAYA MEDICAL&GENARAL STORES
24  Sale    2017-10-07 00:00:00.000 0230    LANCHIPALLI MALLAINAIDU
25  Sale    2017-10-07 00:00:00.000 0231    NEW VENKATADRI SWEETS&COOL DRINKS
27  Sale    2017-10-08 00:00:00.000 0232    LANCHIPALLI MALLAINAIDU
28  Sale    2017-10-08 00:00:00.000 0233    J.BALASUBRAMANYAM
29  Sale    2017-10-08 00:00:00.000 0234    RAJESWARI GENARAL STORES
30  Sale    2017-10-08 00:00:00.000 0235    M/S SRI SAI PROVISINAL&DIGNITY STORES 
31  Sale    2017-10-08 00:00:00.000 0236    B V SUBRAMANYAM
32  Sale    2017-10-09 00:00:00.000 0237    K. MADHUSUDAHANA,KUPPAM
33  Sale    2017-10-09 00:00:00.000 0238    JK SUPER BAZAAR
34  Sale    2017-10-09 00:00:00.000 0239    NEW LAKSHMI PROVISION STORES
35  Sale    2017-10-03 00:00:00.000 0213    RAJU 
36  Sale    2017-10-04 00:00:00.000 0216    BALAJI
42  Sale    2017-11-03 00:00:00.000 0293    LAKSHMI SUPER BAZAAR
43  Sale    2017-11-03 00:00:00.000 0292    SREEDHAR TRADERS
44  Sale    2017-11-02 00:00:00.000 0291    M/S R S PANDURANGA GENARAL MARCHANT
45  Sale    2017-11-02 00:00:00.000 0290    SREEDHAR TRADERS
47  Sale    2017-11-04 00:00:00.000 0294    SRI MURUGAN AGENCY&GENARAL STORES
49  Sale    2017-11-04 00:00:00.000 0295    SRI HARI MEDICALS
50  Sale    2017-11-05 00:00:00.000 0296    M/S SRI SAI PROVISINAL&DIGNITY STORES 
52  Sale    2017-11-05 00:00:00.000 0297    LAKSHMI SUPER BAZAAR
53  Sale    2017-11-05 00:00:00.000 0298    VAMSI KRISHNA SUPER BAZAAR
54  Sale    2017-10-02 00:00:00.000 0210    KA SUPER BAZAAR
55  Sale    2017-10-02 00:00:00.000 0211    SRI MURUGAN AGENCY&GENARAL STORES
```

I tried running the query:

```
    select 
        dp.ITEMNAME,dp.BARCODE, 
        (CAST(dp.QUANTITY AS numeric(18,2))) , 
        ds.BARCODE,
        (CAST(ds.QTY AS numeric(18,2))) as [ClosingStock] 
    from [iBillDB].[dbo].detailpurchases as dp 
    join [iBillDB].[dbo].purchasereport as pr on dp.BARCODE=pr.voucherno 
    join [iBillDB].[dbo].detailsale as ds on ds.ITEMN=dp.ITEMN 
    join [iBillDB].[dbo].salesreport as sr on ds.BARCODE=sr.voucherno 
    where ds.T='R' 
    and dp.ITEMN='106' 
    group by dp.ITEMNAME,dp.QUANTITY,ds.QTY,dp.BARCODE,ds.BARCODE;
```

**I get result as follows:**

```
ITEMNAME        BARCODE cs      BARCODE ClosingStock
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0025    108.00  0225    1.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0025    108.00  0227    1.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0070    108.00  0225    1.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0070    108.00  0227    1.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0025    108.00  0218    18.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0025    108.00  0291    18.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0070    108.00  0218    18.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0070    108.00  0291    18.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0025    108.00  0214    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0025    108.00  0236    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0025    108.00  0293    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0070    108.00  0214    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0070    108.00  0236    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0070    108.00  0293    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0025    108.00  0232    4.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0070    108.00  0232    4.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0025    108.00  0220    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0025    108.00  0231    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0025    108.00  0235    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0070    108.00  0220    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0070    108.00  0231    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0070    108.00  0235    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0021    144.00  0225    1.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0021    144.00  0227    1.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0021    144.00  0218    18.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0021    144.00  0291    18.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0021    144.00  0214    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0021    144.00  0236    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0021    144.00  0293    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0021    144.00  0232    4.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0021    144.00  0220    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0021    144.00  0231    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0021    144.00  0235    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0039    180.00  0225    1.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0039    180.00  0227    1.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0039    180.00  0218    18.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0039    180.00  0291    18.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0039    180.00  0214    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0039    180.00  0236    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0039    180.00  0293    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0039    180.00  0232    4.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0039    180.00  0220    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0039    180.00  0231    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0039    180.00  0235    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0044    270.00  0225    1.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0044    270.00  0227    1.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0044    270.00  0218    18.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0044    270.00  0291    18.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0044    270.00  0214    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0044    270.00  0236    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0044    270.00  0293    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0044    270.00  0232    4.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0044    270.00  0220    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0044    270.00  0231    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0044    270.00  0235    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0014    4860.00 0225    1.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0014    4860.00 0227    1.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0015    4860.00 0225    1.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0015    4860.00 0227    1.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0014    4860.00 0218    18.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0014    4860.00 0291    18.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0015    4860.00 0218    18.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0015    4860.00 0291    18.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0014    4860.00 0214    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0014    4860.00 0236    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0014    4860.00 0293    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0015    4860.00 0214    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0015    4860.00 0236    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0015    4860.00 0293    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0014    4860.00 0232    4.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0015    4860.00 0232    4.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0014    4860.00 0220    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0014    4860.00 0231    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0014    4860.00 0235    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0015    4860.00 0220    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0015    4860.00 0231    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0015    4860.00 0235    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0009    90.00   0225    1.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0009    90.00   0227    1.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0034    90.00   0225    1.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0034    90.00   0227    1.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0009    90.00   0218    18.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0009    90.00   0291    18.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0034    90.00   0218    18.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0034    90.00   0291    18.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0009    90.00   0214    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0009    90.00   0236    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0009    90.00   0293    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0034    90.00   0214    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0034    90.00   0236    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0034    90.00   0293    2.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0009    90.00   0232    4.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0034    90.00   0232    4.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0009    90.00   0220    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0009    90.00   0231    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0009    90.00   0235    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0034    90.00   0220    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0034    90.00   0231    5.00
5STAR 10.1G 5/- 0034    90.00   0235    5.00
```

in the above result The 2ndcolumn is BillNo of Purchases and 3rd column is QTY purchased
4th column is BillNo of Sales and 5th Column is QTY sold

**My assessment is here while Summing up the values are repeated twice.**

*EXPECTED RESULT is:*
**10647**

*Actual Result is:*
**117243**

Comment: I've removed the MySQL tag, as this is obviously for SQL Server, not MySQL. I've also removed VB.net and Visual Studio tags, as they are unrelated to the question. I've added the SQL tag.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner the VB.NET tag is probably as imporant if not more - the query is created by concatenating textbox contents instead of using date parameters. Most likely the unexpected string formatting results in an incorrect filter

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: You mean that `DATE1.Text` and `DATE2.Text` may contain invalid dates, such as day and month confused? That may be, but it doesn't matter whether these string come from VB or any other source. Anyhow, the issue with the query is that join-everything-and-then-try-to-extract-something-meaningful-from-the-murky-intermediate-result thing :-)

Comment: I believe that you get much better responses if you post a link to a http://dbfiddle.uk or http://sqlfiddle.com with prepared data.

Answer (score 1):

You are multplying values by joining unrelated records. (You are combining every purchase detail records with every sales detail record in an item.) You want to join the purchase sum with the sales sum, so aggregate first, join then:

```
select 
  coaleasce(p.itemname, s.itemname) as itemname,
  coaleasce(p.sum_qty, 0) - coaleasce(s.sum_qty, 0) as closing_stock
from
(
  select
    itemname,
    sum(cast(quantity as numeric(18, 2))) as sum_qty
  from detailpurchases
  where barcode in (select voucherno from purchasereport where voucherdate between ? and ?)
  group by itemname
) p
full outer join
(
  select
    itemname,
    sum(cast(qty as numeric(18, 2))) as sum_qty
  from detailsale
  where barcode in (select voucherno from salesreport where voucherdate between ? and ?)
  and T = 'R'
  group by itemname
) s on s.itemname = p.itemname;
```